# Django: django-autocomplete-light does not work properly

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using `django-autocomplete-light` in django 1.8. But I don't know how to use it in `forms.py`. Instead of autocomplete field I see a select field. I followed the instructions from [here](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html).

In `models.py` I have:

```
class icd_10(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True,primary_key=True,null=False,blank=False)
    icd_10_desc = models.CharField('ICD-10 description',max_length=80,null=True,blank=True)
    icd_10_code = models.CharField('ICD-10 code',max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.icd_10_desc)

class Diagnosis(models.Model):

    diagnosis_option = models.ManyToManyField(DiagnosisOption)
    record_of_genotype = models.CharField(max_length=45,null=True,blank=True)
    icd_10_desc = models.ManyToManyField(icd_10)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Demographic)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient)
```

In `settings.py` I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
     ...
)
```

In `views.py` I have:

```
class IcdTenAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        #Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return icd_10.objects.none()

        qs = icd_10.objects.all()

        if self.q:
             qs = qs.filter(icd_10_desc__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

In `urls.py` I have:

```
url(r'^icd10-autocomplete/$','eReg.views.IcdTenAutocomplete',name='icd10-autocomplete'),
```

And in `forms.py` I have:

```
class DiagnosisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(DiagnosisForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset (
                # 'patient',
                '<b>Diagnosis information</b>',

                'diagnosis_option',
                'icd_10_desc',

                ),


            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = Diagnosis
        exclude = ['patient', 'author']

        list_display = ('patient', 'pub_date', 'author')
        widgets={'icd10_desc' : autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='icd10-autocomplete')}
```

When I run it directly from browser it works properly. I get

```
{"pagination": {"more": false}, "results": [{"text": "Thalassemia", "id": 8}, {"text": "Thalassemia trait", "id": 12}, {"text": "Thalassemia, unspecified", "id": 15}]}
```

So, do I miss a proper javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution! I had to include the code below in my template:

```
{% block footer %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dal-yourlabs.rhcloud.com/static/collected/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

{{ frm.media }}

{% endblock %}
```

And the code below in base.html from which my template inherits data.

```
<link src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/select2.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would've expected `{{frm.media}}` to cover all the resources except jquery, i.e. all the javascript you included in your base.html seemed unneeded to me. But I'm not sure.